# Нужно сделать concat с помощью reduce

Tags: javascript

```
const concat = (array, elementToBeAdded) => {
    return array.reduce((function(previous, current) {
        return previous + current
    }, `${elementToBeAdded}`));
}

const cat = concat(['a','b'], 'c');

console.log(cat);
```

выводит в консоль ошибку:
TypeError: c is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из-за лишних круглых скобок

```
array.reduce((function(previous, current) {...}, `...`));
```

, запятая внутри них рассматривалась не как разделитель аргументов функции, а как [оператор запятая](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Результатом применения этого оператора становилась строка `` `${elementToBeAdded}` ``

И именно эта строка передавалась в качестве аргумента функции `reduce`. Как следствие - указанная ошибка.

Для решения достаточно убрать лишние скобки.

Answer (score 5):

У Вас были лишние скобки в функции `array.reduce((...))`.

```js
const concat = (array, elementToBeAdded) => {
    return array.reduce((previous, current) => {
        return previous + current;
    }, elementToBeAdded);
}

const cat = concat(['a','b'], 'c');

console.log(cat);
```